# Python PATH unable to be located

Tags: python-3.x, csv, import, path

trying to open a .csv file within my script, have the .csv file UTF-8 and yet I can't work out where to save it in order to be able to open it within python, I keep getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'billing_profile_test.csv'`
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hello are you working with Idle? If so you should be able to save as (ctrl + shift + s) to prompt a save menu to pop up. From there you will know the working directory where you should put your file, other than that a good place to look is 
**`C:\Users\{Your User}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32`**